# Dwarftown instantly hostile

Tags: adom

I've just encountered something strange in ADOM: my character reached Dwarftown for the first time, and my first step off the stairs is into a hostile town.

The shop is closed with a sign on the door and I'm surrounded by angry dwarves.

I had scummed the save file a few times so I tried going back with no items whatsoever (and already no corruptions) but the same thing happened.

Is this just something that happens or am I triggering it somehow? If so, can I make the Dwarftown peaceful again?

Comment: Did you attack someone in there?

Comment: @Isuka no, I just walked down the stairs and then one tile in.  Boom, surrounded by angry dwarves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah ha. I hadn't dropped the items I was wearing.

And I was wearing a Ring Mail of Hate.

Makes sense.